# Defining private Class method

Tags: ruby

This code works:

```
class TestPluralize
  def pluralize(value)
    value != 1 ? 's' : ''
  end

  def test_it(v)
    pluralize(v)
  end
end

t = TestPluralize.new
#=> #<TestPluralize:0xb7f55a70>
t.test_it(5)
#=> "s"
```

But I want to make `pluralize` private.  So I did this:

```
class TestPluralize
  class << self
    private
    def pluralize(value)
      value != 1 ? 's' : ''
    end
  end

  def test_it(v)
    self.pluralize(v)
  end
end

t = TestPluralize.new
#=> #<TestPluralize:0xb8831b80>
t.test_it(5)
NoMethodError: undefined method `pluralize' for #<TestPluralize:0xb8831b80>
    from (irb):10:in `test_it'
    from (irb):15
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing *two* things in your examples:

- whether or not `pluralize` is `private`
- what class it is defined in

`private` is a red herring here, you would get the exact same error whether `pluralize` is `private` or not. (Note that the error is *not* "private method called" but rather "undefined method"!) In the second case, you are defining `pluralize` in a totally different class than in the first example. In your first example, `pluralize` is a method defined in `TestPluralize`, whereas in the second example, it is a method in `TestPluralize`'s singleton class (the first is also sometimes called an "instance method" and the second a "class method", although that's not really correct, because the difference is not in the methods but in which class they are defined in).

You could do one of these three:

```
class TestPluralize
  private def pluralize(value)
    value != 1 ? 's' : ''
  end

  def test_it(v)
    pluralize(v)
  end
end

class TestPluralize
  def pluralize(value)
    value != 1 ? 's' : ''
  end
  private :pluralize

  def test_it(v)
    pluralize(v)
  end
end

class TestPluralize
  private

  def pluralize(value)
    value != 1 ? 's' : ''
  end

  public # or just switch the two methods around

  def test_it(v)
    pluralize(v)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to make `pluralize` private you can add `private :pluralize` to make just that method private (another way is to have `private` and then all the methods you want to be private fall after that in the class, but the first way allows doing so with only changing one line).

```
class TestPluralize
  def pluralize(value)
    value != 1 ? 's' : ''
  end

  def test_it(v)
    pluralize(v)
  end

  private :pluralize
end
```

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Private for more details on private methods.

Comment: Yes, that works, but why doesn't my original implementation?

Comment: Because in your first code, `pluralize` is a method defined in `TestPluralize`, whereas in the second example, it is a method in `TestPluralize`'s singleton class (the first is also sometimes called an "instance method" and the second a "class method", although that's not really correct, because the difference is not in the methods but in which class they are defined in).

Comment: From the [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Private) included in my answer: Private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver at all, even if that receiver is "self"

Comment: Ah, I get it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also just define `#pluralize` *after* you define `#test_it`. That way, `#test_it` stays public and `#pluralize` becomes private. It doesn't matter which order you define methods in a class, other than `#initialize` being first.